# Multiplayer Games iOS. Is Gamecenter is the only option?

Tags: ios, game-center

I am learning about multiplayer gaming scenarios in iOS and every possible tutorial I come across mentions enabling multiplayer gaming only through Gamecenter. Is Gamecenter is the only option to develop a multiplayer game in iOS? Is there a way a player can invite other to play using facebook or other means?

Thank you

Comment: Sure. What ever you can build. You can have your own server to which the app is talking to and sure you can build an invitation system which uses facebook. The question is if you are capable to do so.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.developer.gree.net/en/platform/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: It totally depends on you.

Descriptive answer : There are many options available to you for creating multiplayer game in iOS.

for online leaderboards you can use either "Gamecentre" or "Open Feint", or you can write leaderboard of your own

for sending and receiving data from one device to another there are many options available, one of them is using [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com) for the same(it is not free) or you may write an engine similar to pubnub for your own specific needs using java(I said java because it handles such type of applications very efficiently)

It is recommended to use FB SDK for inviting players as it is very easy to integrate and increase social visibility of your app too.

**EDIT :**

you may also use AFNetworking 2.0 with rocket.